# How do I make the transition between view controllers and return from each to the main view con.?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a MainViewController with a table view. When I click on a cell, the ChartViewController opens. It has a Back button to return to the MainViewController and a button to go to the SummaryViewController. The SummaryViewController button has a button to go to the ChartViewController and a Back button, but it also goes back to the ChartViewController. How do I return to the MainViewController using the Back button?

Transition code from Chart View Controller to SummaryViewController:

```
@IBAction func onSummaryButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
        if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StockSummaryViewController") as? StockSummaryViewController {
         navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add in ChartViewController when you create SummaryViewController

...
summaryViewController.delegate = self

in SummaryViewController add a variable

```
weak var delegate: SummaryViewControllerDelegate?
```

and when user click "backButton" in SummaryViewController add

```
{
 ...
delegate?.backClick()
}
```

in ChartViewController add

```
extension ChartViewController: SummaryViewControllerDelegate {
   func backClick() {
      self.dismiss(animation: true, completion: nil)
    //or 
//self.popViewController(animation: true)

   }
}
```

and finally define anywhere

```
protocol SummaryViewControllerDelegate: class {\
   func backClick()
}
```